# Swiftui searchable Cancel button

Tags: swiftui, ios15, searchable, cancel-button

I have a `NavigationView` with `.searchable`, when clicking Cancel I want to go to the previous View like Back button.
İ use `@Environment(\.isSearching)`, it is running, I can print Searching canceled but how to navigate to the previous View ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to the changes made to `isSearching`, and pop your view using `@Environment(\.presentationMode)`:

```
.onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
    guard !newValue else {return}
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    //for iOS 16 +, use dismiss.callAsFunction()
}
```

Note: `presentationMode` is first deprecated in iOS 15+, so for newer versions use `@Environment(\.dismiss)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 13+, you can use `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss`
And then use `dismiss()` in the action